# Is there a way to wrap label around input in symfony2?

Tags: forms, symfony, label, twig

Question about symfony2 form component and its templating:

I've got a bunch of checkboxes to style (about 10 in one form row). Usually I use `<label>` tag this way: `<label><input/> some text</label>` but I can't find a way to change it in the form template (form_div_layout.html.twig). I can't even find a way to wrap any tag around input widget and its label and I always end up with markup like this: `<input/> <some_tag><label>some text</label></some_tag>` or `<some_tag><input/></some_tag> <label>some text</label>` which is not very useful, to say the least...

Googled quite a bit, but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates

You can override any of the default twig templates by creating another file with the same name  in your app/resources folder.

In your case you want to override the form_div_layout.html.twig template, copy it from the bundle to app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig, customize away and symfony will use that rather than the default.

EDIT: Once you have overridden the template you could modify the `{% block checkbox_widget %}` to have the input wrapped with the label tags using the twig vars

```
<label{% for attrname,attrvalue in attr %} {{attrname}}="{{attrvalue}}"{% endfor %}>
  {{label|trans }} 
  <input type="checkbox" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} /> 
</label>
```

You will also need to remove the 'generic_label' definition, meaning every other block requires modifications.

Comment: Guys, I know how to customize and override layouts, it's just I can't find a way to wrap `<label>` tag around input. And I seriously doubt if it's possible at all, since twig template for label looks like this: `{{ form_label(form.field_name) }}` and is rendered as one element, obviously. Not opening and closing tag. Right now I'm just using this piece of jQ: `$('input+label').each(function(){$(this).prepend($(this).prev());});` but it looks like a temporary fix...

Comment: Hmmm, is there any reason why you can't put label before or after the input? I know that isn't what you are asking but having the input inside the label breaks w3 spec and could possibly cause you issues down the track. From W3: "The label itself may be positioned before or after the associated control." http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL

Comment: The reason is much easier styling - just set label to 50% width, display inline-block, fixed height, and You've got inputs sorted out, while with a set of inline elements it becomes a mess. As to the W3C - last time I checked input could be placed inside the label, only labels without `for` attribute might be not WCAG compliant: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_label.asp

Comment: Fair enough - I'm not a twig guru but I still think you can achieve what you want in the form_div_layout.html.twig file, you'll just need to do some heavy restructuring. Can you modify the {% block checkbox_widget %} to have the input wrapped with the label tags using the twig vars? <label{% for attrname,attrvalue in attr %} {{attrname}}="{{attrvalue}}"{% endfor %}>{{ label|trans }}        <input type="checkbox" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />  </label>

Comment: It actually works. Kind of :-)  Only issue is that I needed to remove 'generic_label' definition, so each and every other block requires modifications. Edit Your answer and I'll accept it, thank You very much.

Answer (score 6):

Whistlegreg is correct that you will need to override the twig form templates. However, you do not need to remove the `{% block generic_label %}` block. See his answer if you need help on how to override the templates.

In order to wrap the checkbox input tags with a label, the first step will be to override the `{% block choice_widget %}` block and remove the `{{ form_label(child) }}` line from the `{% if expanded %}` section that prints out a separate label.

```
{% block choice_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if expanded %}
        <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        {% for child in form %}
            {{ form_widget(child) }}
        {#  {{ form_label(child) }} <--------------------- remove this line #}  
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% else %}
    <select {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if multiple %} multiple="multiple"{% endif %}>
        {% if empty_value is not none %}
            <option value="">{{ empty_value|trans }}</option>
        {% endif %}
        {% if preferred_choices|length > 0 %}
            {% set options = preferred_choices %}
            {{ block('widget_choice_options') }}
            {% if choices|length > 0 and separator is not none %}
                <option disabled="disabled">{{ separator }}</option>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
        {% set options = choices %}
        {{ block('widget_choice_options') }}
    </select>
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget %}
```

Now you will just need to handle printing the label in the `{% block checkbox_widget %}` block.

```
{% block checkbox_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    <label  for="{{ id }}"><input type="checkbox" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />{{ label|trans }}</label>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock checkbox_widget %}
```

You will need to do the same for `{% block radio_widget %}` since it would not otherwise have a label now.

```
{% block radio_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    <label  for="{{ id }}"><input type="radio" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />{{ label|trans }}</label>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock radio_widget %}
```

Comment: @ilanco works fine for me in 2.0.15:

`<div class="control-group">
 <label class="control-label">Position type</label>
 <div class="controls expanded-choice-group">
  <label for="profile_edit_position_type_full-time" class="checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" id="profile_edit_position_type_full-time" name="profile_edit[position_type][full-time]" value="full-time" />
   Full-time
  </label>
  ...snip for brevity...
  <span class="help-inline"></span>
 </div>
</div>`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to define blocks for the rows of specific form widget types, e.g. `{% block checkbox_row %}`. I discovered this here: http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=57986#p153546

All that is then required to wrap the label around the widget for checkboxes is the following:

```
{% block checkbox_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div>
        {% if not compound %}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'for': id}) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if required %}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
        {% endif %}
        <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {% if label is empty %}
            {% set label = name|humanize %}
        {% endif %}
        </label>
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock checkbox_row %}
```

The label code has been copied and pasted from `{% block form_label %}`.  I've put the form error below the widget as I'm using Zurb's Foundation framework.

The code for radio buttons, is more complicated because `{% block radio_row %}` doesn't appear to exist, so you have to take Whistlegreg's advice and edit the `{% block choice_widget %}` block, in Symfony 2.1 that's actually now the `{% block choice_widget_expanded %}`. Here's my code:

```
{% block choice_widget_expanded %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
    {% for child in form %}
        {% set child_label = child.get('label') %}
        {% if child_label is not sameas(false) %}
            {% set child_id = child.get('id') %}
            {% set child_compound = child.get('compound') %}
            {% set child_required = child.get('required') %}
            {% set child_label_attr = child.get('label_attr') %}
            {% if not child_compound %}
                {% set child_label_attr = child_label_attr|merge({'for': child_id}) %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if child_required %}
                {% set child_label_attr = child_label_attr|merge({'class': (child_label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
            {% endif %}
            <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in child_label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>
        {% endif %}
        {{ form_widget(child) }}
        {% if child_label is not sameas(false) %}
            {% if child_label is empty %}
                {% set child_label = name|humanize %}
            {% endif %}
            {{ child_label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}
            </label>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_expanded %}
```

Tested and working in Symfony 2.1.9 DEV.

Comment: Method "get" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by changing the form_row block.

Try something like this:

```
{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <label>
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </label>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```

But take care, it's definitively not a very flexible solution...
You should probably use this only with a specific Type, not for all.
Anyway, you must use `form_row` to get it work.

Comment: It won't work, because all inputs are in one row. Whole structure looks more or less like this: a few form rows, first two rows with group of checkboxes, other rows with one text input or select inside. So wrapping one row isn't of any help. I think I'll stay with jQ for this specific form, I plan to build some custom UI on top of it, anyway (jquery.ui sliders, etc).

Comment: You can use this trick only for a given Type. Choice for example by defining the choice_row block.
You also can do this for only one given type by defining the _your_type_name_row block.